# How can we implement CI/CD on Azure VMSS created using custom image

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-pipelines-release-task

I have created VMSS using custom image. I have hosted web application build in .Net MVC on VMSS. I have configured CI/CD from Azure DevOps by referring following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/azure/deploy-azure-scaleset?view=azure-devops .

It is showing error `D:\a\_temp\1575277721063\packer\packer.exe failed with return code: 1` . Any suggestion/recommendation is appreciated.
Below is some failed commands in Log:

```
 1. azure-arm: resources.DeploymentsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=200 -- Original Error: Long running operation terminated with status 'Failed': Code="DeploymentFailed" Message="At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details."
 2. Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
    2019-12-02T09:57:31.5222618Z --> azure-arm: resources.DeploymentsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=200 -- Original Error: Long running operation terminated with status 'Failed': Code="DeploymentFailed" Message="At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details."

 3. 2019-12-02T09:57:31.5222868Z ==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

Comment: Hi Mike, please follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-operations?tabs=azure-portal#get-deployment-operations-and-error-message) to get more details about your error message. As I know, many causes can cause this kind of issue, so it's hard to know what's really happening without the further info.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message (DeploymentFailed) from the pipeline  is a generic one, it would be tough to investigate the issue without looking at the underlying logs or your pipeline details.

For troubleshooting it further, please try the following:

- [View deployment history with Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-history?tabs=azure-portal) as mentioned in the error message itself.
- [Gather logs to diagnose problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#my-pipeline-starts-but-fails-to-complete-successfully), such as debug/verbose pipeline logs, worker/agent diagnostics logs etc..
- Look at some [common issues and resolutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#common-issues-and-resolutions) if it helps.
- Send feedback and report problems through the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) for Azure DevOps.